# How do I draw inside an object in Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape

[image]

I have the image shown above where the black colored stroke is the outline of the cloud. I also have a slightly offsetted blue color fill. What should I do to put the blue color fill *inside* the outline (along with the whitespace)? I tried using the clip option, but it wasn't helpful.

[image]

The above picture shows how I would want it. As you can see, the whitespace is still there, but the fill lies inside the stroke.

Comment: Are paths both the outline and the fill? You can [align](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Align.html) them. Or you can simply delete the cyan path and fill with the same color the outline path.

Comment: Hey, one of them is just the stroke (the black one), the other is only fill. I want the blue fill to appear only inside the black outline, not outside it.

Comment: Ok: you can select both the paths and align them, it's a very simple operation: have you tried it? If you are in difficult, please post somewhere the SVG file and link it to your question, so that it is possible to provide an adequate answer.

Comment: I updated the question to remove ambiguity. Please check.

Comment: I see, is more clear now. At the moment I have no time to give a decent answer, I will reply later. If you are searching to give a light effect to the cloud, you can duplicate the path with the stroke (Ctrl+D), select the duplicate and the blue path and perform a difference (Ctrl+-), eventually bring the blue path to the bottom (PageDown).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19579/discussion-between-sk8erboi-and-paolo-gibellini).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are starting from two paths, one filled in cyan without stroke paint and the other with a black stroke and without fill; and assuming that the filled path is at the bottom, we have a similar situation:

[image: base cloud]

You have to perform a few simple steps:

1. Select and *duplicate* the path with the black stroke while pressing **Ctrl-D**

[image: duplicate path]

2. Maintaining selected the duplicate, hold **Shift** key, select the path with the cyan fill and obtain an *intersection* pressing **Ctrl+***

[image: final image]

You can tweak a little the cloud:

[image: final cloud]

You can obtain a similar effect (although not flat) starting from a path with border and fill and using *Filters->Bevels->Combined lighting* or other analogous filter:

[image: with a filter]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you want to do the following:

- Duplicate your black path.
- Select your black path and your cloud.
- *Path → Intersection.*