# In Inkscape how to create a fill only above a line

Tags: vector, fill

I need to create for the pink line a similar thing to what is there for the red line. If I follow [this steps](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/44674/how-do-i-draw-inside-an-object-in-inkscape) Inkscape fails to recognise properly my pink vector and I get just the filling all over the place. Do you have a nice way for me to fill only the area above the lines? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking. What about the red line to you want to replicate with the pink line? The only different I see at the moment is that the red line is thicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking how you could fill the space above the pink line with it's own color, correct? If so, here's but one way to do it (there are many ways).

Essentially, you need to have a shape to fill it in with a color, so we need to make a shape.

[image]

**Image 1**: This is the base drawing. A box with your line in it.

**Image 2**: I duplicated the red line (and made it pink for clarity) and the box. Duplicating it creates a copy directly on top of the original line, so you don't lose the original. I then converted the line to a shape by going to `Path` > `Object To Path`. I now have two shapes: the big box, and the line that has been converted to a shape.

**Image 3**: I selected the two new image and then used `Path` > `Division`. This takes the top image (the 'line') and uses it to cut up the bottom image (the box). I now have 3 shapes. I deleted the bottom two which leaves me with...

**Image 4**: This is now the shape of the 'space above the red line' that you can color any way you want. I removed the original line and box form this last photo just for clarity.